# How is this rearranged?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've got the following integration question:

$dx/dt = kx - a(x^2)$.

I've been following a textbook in how to go through the steps but I'm not sure how they rearranged a step.

They value K as $K = x(0)/b-x(0)$ and have $x/b-x = e^C.e^(kt)$ to get$x(t) = b.K.e^(kt)/1+K.e^(kt)$ and I'm not sure how they got to that.

Any help would be great thanks :)

Comment: Sorry but your explanation is really messy.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you may rewrite the PDE as $$\dfrac{dx}{Kx-ax^2}=dt$$which has the following form$$dx\left(\dfrac{1}{Kx}-\dfrac{1}{K(x-\frac{K}{a})}\right)=dt$$by integrating we obtain$$\dfrac{1}{K}\ln|x|-\dfrac{1}{K}\ln|x-\frac{K}{a}|=t+C_1$$or $$\dfrac{|x|}{|x-\frac{K}{a}|}=C_2e^{Kt}$$can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation as
$$\frac {dt}{dx}=\frac 1{k x-ax^2}$$ Use partial fractions to get
$$\frac {dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{k x}-\frac{a}{k (a x-k)}$$ Integrate both sides
$$t+C=\frac{\log (|x|)}{k}-\frac{\log (|k-a x|)}{k}\implies \log \left(\left|\frac{x}{k-a x}\right|\right)=kt+C$$ Exponentiate, isolate $x$ and apply the condition.

Answer (score 0):

**My guess of what they did:**

You can write the equation as
$$x'=ax(b-x)$$ where $ab=k$.

Then notice that

$$\left(\frac x{b-x}\right)'=\frac{bx'}{(b-x)^2}.$$

So the equation is

$$\left(\frac x{b-x}\right)'=k\frac x{b-x}$$

which is easy to integrate, giving

$$\frac x{b-x}=Ke^{kt}.$$

And by the initial condition,

$$K=\frac{x_0}{b-x_0}.$$

Finally,

$$x=\frac{bKe^{kt}}{1+Ke^{kt}}=\frac{kx_0e^{kt}}{k+ax_0(e^{kt}-1)}.$$